# Search results in results

Tags: vocabulary, internet

1. "*Term* has X search results"
2. "A search for *term* has X results*
3. "A search for *term* resulted in X results"

Is anyone else confused by this? A "search" generally "results" in something, but lacking an alternative to "results" (like "items" or "records") you end up with duplicity (#3). No. 2, the alternative, has "search" "contain" the results, which isn't more correct. What do you think?

Comment: It's quite true you can say that *a "search" generally "results" in something*, but it would be silly to say *a search results in **results***. Either replace the ***verb*** (with, say, ***returns***) or replace the ***noun*** with something like ***matches*** or ***instances***.

Comment: (Btw - ***duplicity*** doesn't mean the same thing as ***duplication***, which is the word you should have used above.)

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about saying *a search resulted in many search results*. The word, correctly, is a noun in the first use and an attributive noun in the second use. But, stylistically, it's redundant and sounds awkward. Since it's made obvious from the first part of the sentence that a search took place, there is no need to qualify what kind of results were found in the second part of the sentence.

Comment: **yield** is a good verb here.

Comment: A search for "exculpatory" on Google yields about 3,000,000 **hits**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some useful alternatives (credit goes to @FumbleFingers):

> Either replace the ***verb*** (with, say, ***returns***) or replace the ***noun*** with something like ***matches*** or ***instances***.

Answer (score 2):

> “Seek and ye shall **find**”

*Mathew 7:7 KJV*

So

> The search *found*…

solves a self-inflicted problem.

Comment: Didn't the _person_ find, not the _search_?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to search engines and internet speak. In that context, a search *displays* results.  "Display" is the verb that's used.

Examples:

> "While search engines [display](https://www.searchenginewatch.com/2007/03/23/search-engine-results-chart/) results from many different
>   sources..."
>
> "...search engines that [display](http://www.findingdulcinea.com/guides/Technology/Internet/Dulcineas-Guide-to-Searching-on-the-Web.pg_02.html) results in..."
>
> "A search engine results page [displays](https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/search-engine-optimization/how-to-decipher-search-engine-results/)..."